# Filtering 2 dates from a string with variable length

Tags: java, string, date

I am working with a java application that returns a string which contains 2 dates.

The months are written out in full (in dutch) and the day can be either one or two charcaters long (eg. 1 december 2017 or 12 december 2017)

I need to filter both dates from the string and convert them to date type, so I can calculate the difference between the two.

I have managed to come up with the following code, which does work. I have the feeling it can be done with a lot less code though.

I've been reading up on regular expressions, but I am unsure if they can be used, given that the date's in my string arený always the same length.

```
String baseString =
    "Bijgewerkt tot: 30 november 2017 15:39. Nieuwe bundel: 20 december 2017";

String baseStringEdited = baseString    
    .replaceAll(" januari ", " 01 ")
    .replaceAll(" februari ", " 02 ")
    .replaceAll(" maart ", " 03 ")
    .replaceAll(" april ", " 04 ")
    .replaceAll(" mei ", " 05 ")
    .replaceAll(" juni ", " 06 ")
    .replaceAll(" juli ", " 07 ")
    .replaceAll(" augustus ", " 08 ")
    .replaceAll(" september ", " 09 ")
    .replaceAll(" oktober ", " 10 ")
    .replaceAll(" november ", " 11 ")
    .replaceAll(" december ", " 12 ")
    .replaceAll(" 1 ", " 01 ")
    .replaceAll(" 2 ", " 02 ")
    .replaceAll(" 3 ", " 03 ")
    .replaceAll(" 4 ", " 04 ")
    .replaceAll(" 5 ", " 05 ")
    .replaceAll(" 6 ", " 06 ")
    .replaceAll(" 7 ", " 07 ")
    .replaceAll(" 8 ", " 08 ")
    .replaceAll(" 9 ", " 09 ");

String dateOne = baseStringEdited.substring(16, 26);
String dateTwo = baseStringEdited.substring(49);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MM yyyy"); 

String input = dateOne; 
String input2 = dateTwo;
Long diff = null;

try {
    Date dateOneFormatted = dateFormatter.parse(input); 
    Date dateTwoFormatted = dateFormatter.parse(input2);
    diff = dateOneFormatted.getTime() - dateTwoFormatted.getTime();

} catch (ParseException e) { 
    System.out.println("Unparseable using " + dateFormatter); 
}

System.out.println(TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

Comment: Since you stated that your code works, what is your question again?

Comment: You can use regular expressions to get the dates. A fitting regex for the date-part with an optional time part would be `\d\d \w+ \d{4} (\d\d\:\d\d)?`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about working code belong on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Tips: Work with proper objects when feasible, rather than mucking about with strings and regex. We have the excellent java.time classes, so use them. And when serializing data-time values as strings, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the java time API, you can simply adapt the formatters to "ignore" the extra text. Also, if you specify the correct `Locale`, you can parse the month names without having to map them manually.

```
String[] dates = baseString.split("\\. ");

DateTimeFormatter firstFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Bijgewerkt tot: 'd MMMM uuuu HH:mm", new Locale("nl"));
LocalDateTime first = LocalDateTime.parse(dates[0], firstFmt );

DateTimeFormatter secondFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Nieuwe bundel: 'd MMMM uuuu", new Locale("nl"));
LocalDate second = LocalDate.parse(dates[1], secondFmt);

System.out.println("First: " + first);
System.out.println("Second: " + second);
```

Note that the code can easily be adapted to use a `SimpleDateFormat` if you don't have a choice.

Comment: This looks a lot better and seems to work just as well, thanks!

Comment: I like the “if you don't have a choice” part. In other words, I do recommend using `java.time` as in this answer.

Comment: @assylias I suggest you specify it only exists from Java 8 on to avoid confusion

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy, `java.time`, also known as JSR-310, has been backported to Java 6 and 7 in [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). You can use it from Java 6 through Java 9 (and counting).

Comment: Good thing they backported it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would replace :

```
String dateOne = baseStringEdited.substring(16, 26);
String dateTwo = baseStringEdited.substring(49);
```

because it works for certain inputs, with :

```
String digits = baseStringEdited.replaceAll("\\D+","");
String dateOne=digits.substring(0,8);
String dateTwo=digits.substring(12);
```

which is suitable for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using **regular expressions** and **LocalDate**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestDate {
    public static String inputString = "Bijgewerkt tot: 30 november 2017 15:39. Nieuwe bundel: 20 december 2017";
    private static final Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile(
            "(?sim)(\\d{1,2}\\s(januari|februari|maart|april|mei|juni|juli|augustus|september|oktober|november|december)\\s\\d{4})");
    private static final Locale dutch = new Locale("nl", "NL");
    private static DateTimeFormatter f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(dutch);
        Date[] dateList = new Date[2];

        Matcher regexMatcher = datePattern.matcher(inputString);
        Date date;
        LocalDate ld;
        int i = 0;
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            ld = LocalDate.parse(regexMatcher.group(1), f);
            date = Date.from(ld.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            dateList[i] = date;
            i++;
        }
        Long diff = dateList[0].getTime() - dateList[1].getTime();
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    }
}
```